# What happens when Flash accesses an https resource?

Tags: flash, security, ssl, https, crossdomain.xml

If a swf located at http://example.com/test.swf makes a request to https://secure.com/webservice.xml, what happens? Adobe's documentation on cross domain policy files notes the "secure" attribute.

> secure: [HTTPS and Sockets only,
>   optional] Specifies whether access is
>   granted only to HTTPS documents from
>   the specified origin (true) or to all
>   documents from the specified origin
>   (false). If secure is not specified in
>   an HTTPS policy file, it defaults to
>   true. Using false in an HTTPS policy
>   file is not recommended because this
>   compromises the security offered by
>   HTTPS; for example, allowing
>   man-in-the-middle attacks to gain
>   access to the HTTPS data protected by
>   the policy file.

Does this mean the Flash player will actually make an HTTP request, rather than HTTPS? Is the issue that there's a presumption of less trust for .swf files being served from a non-secure domain? If the Flash player makes a proper SSL request, I don't see where the additional man-in-the-middle vulnerability comes from. And if it doesn't, I have to think the web server would probably be configured to reject it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If you set attribute `secure` to `false` Flash application wouldn't make an `http` request. It would make `https` request to source that is published through `https`. But the main idea is that this attribute set to `false` allows Flash to make connections to other `http` resources. "Man in the middle" attack could be made in this moment. Imagine situation. Your Flash application loads some documents from `https`, and process them on some web server, using it's api, but through `http`, not secured, connection. Data that was loaded from `https` would be passed by Flash to web server through simple `http`. If you set `secure` attribute to `true` this will tell Flash that documents from `https` require security. And Flash would not make simple `http` request from that time anymore, because data from `https` could be probably been inserted in this not secure requests by program algorithm.