# Login/signup functionality on multiple domains

Tags: ssl, authentication, dns, jsonp

I have a client who has a number of domains, say www.abc.com, www.xyz.com, and one domain that gets used for login/signup functionality--login.company.com. login.company.com has an SSL certificate, and the other domains do not. The client would prefer not to purchase additional SSL certs for the other domains. Currently the interface that a user sees when signing up is largely controlled by login.company.com. The client would like a sort of API for that functionality, so that www.abc.com could control it's own interface--maybe Flash, maybe HTML/JS. Every option I've come up with has at least one issue...

1) Host a JSONP web service on login.company.com and use JS/Ajax to communicate with it - usernames/passwords would be sent on the querystring 
2) Host any sort of web service on login.company.com and use Flash to communicate with it - Flash would be a problem on mobile web sites and [I'm not sure how that would work anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115854/what-happens-when-flash-accesses-an-https-resource) 
3) Essentially create a proxy service on www.abc.com to accept requests from the UI and pass them to a web service hosted on login.company.com - www.abc.com doesn't have an SSL cert. 
4) Set up hidden iframes on www.abc.com's pages to communicate with login.company.com - I don't think this will even work

Are there other options I'm missing? If it matters, back-end for login.company.com and most instances of www.abc.com would be in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

run your own open id server http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run-your-own-identity-server and migrate your other applications to supporting openid.

Comment: As I understand it, the identity server is still responsible for the UI of entering a username/password, or creating an account, not the consumer site, which is what I'm looking for.